# Installing mod_security2.so on Apache 2.4.23 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, apache, owasp, mod-security

I'm a new technical with **mod_security configuation**.

My problem is I want to install mod_security on **Apache 2.4.23** on **windows 7**.

Source Files : https://www.apachelounge.com/download/

**My configuration** in `httpd.conf` is:

```
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2/mod_security2.so
Include conf/modsecurity.conf
```

***Referrence*** http://mewbies.com/how_to_install_mod_security_for_apache_tutorial.htm

After I save the `httpd.conf` file, and start Apache, it's not working.

Maybe the problem is I do not replace the **libxml2.dll** file? but from the zip file that i download, it's not exist this file.

Please help me. I'm waiting for your answer, thanks.

Comment: "It's not working" is not very helpful. What do you mean? Apache won't start? ModSecurity isn't blocking what it's supposed to? Something else? Anything in Apache error files?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I mean Apache can not start (Error)  when i try to LoadModule.

Comment: Hello @BazzaDP, I found the problem is occurred when i including this line: Include [conf/modsecurity.conf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Us1khESxowTHRBdm91eWJ5aGs/view?usp=sharing). I try to find the solution but get nothing. please help me.. i'm waiting for your reply.

Comment: Does that file exist? What are the contents of that file?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to successfully configure mod_security with Apache 2.4.28 (latest version present at: https://www.apachelounge.com/download/ at the time of posting this reply).

Here are the steps I followed (referring to the same link as posted in question):

- Copy libcurl.dll and yajl.dll to the \bin directory
- Copy mod_security2.so to the \modules directory
- Copy modsecurity.conf to \conf directory (and modify the file as given in mewbies tutorial). Also create an empty unicode.mapping file at this path
- Modify the the httpd.conf file as given in mewbies tutorial
- Create an empty modsec_audit.log file under /logs

Also ensure that you take the latest apache version and mod_security version from apachelounge. As in my case using the mod_security module with my old apache (2.4.10) led to version APR version mismatch error.

Comment: thanks man. saved me a lot of time doing this on our production server

Answer (score 1):

In the file modsecurity.conf you have to configure the SecAuditLog var with a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

Look for errors in Event Viewer (eventvwr.msc)
There must be an error containing something like:
...httpd.exe: Syntax error on line ? of ?:/.../Apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_security2.so into server: ...